# MySQL SELECT reverse query by DB physical insertion

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'EN'
```

I would like to modify selection in reverse (desc) order by it physically has been inserted to db, without any index usage (something like: DESC NO-INDEX)?

Is it possible?

Comment: @user166489. Do not think that right answer will only be yes:) Actually no is the right answer however you could accept the one with best reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM store items with insertion order, and fill deleted rows with a new one (you can see it in select * from... without order). the insertion orde not saved in DB  by default (you can, if you want to use Auto Incerment field to store this order).

INNODB store rows by PK, so you can `select ... from ... order by PK desc`, regardless when the rows was inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a column that reflects physical insertion order, you can't (using an index or not).

You can only order queries by the data they contain. If you didn't store an insertion timestamp or id of some form or other, you can't produce the order you want.

Comment: Does MySQL table keeps any unique row id? Like RECID or ROWID to be sorted by?

Answer (score 0):

Due to various space reuse policies within the DB it is not really possible. Probably the closest you an get is to read the records without any order specified and then traverse your resultSet in opposite direction.

Comment: To you mean to process reverse array after selection it a good idea? Because table has about 2kk rows too big...

Comment: Use `LIMIT` and process it one page at-a-time.